# background image not showing css and is automatically set to none

Tags: css, background-image

i have a div with a background image `<div id='mcts1'></div>`
now when i view it in chrome, the image does not show, and when press F12 [inspect element], this is what i see:
    `<div id="mcts1" style="background-image: none;">...`...
    `</div>`
now i'm wondering how did it happened that the background-image property was set to none when i actually declared it in the css.
here is the css file together with the code snippet where i echoed the `<div id="mcts1">`fiddler file here:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/marsbox2013/jLHMS/)

Comment: where are your css file and the image stored (paths)?

Comment: the css is in a css folder while the nav.png is in a folder named images.
project/css/styles.css
project/images/nav.png

Comment: so the paths seem to be fine, i can't see the problem. do you mind setting up a fiddle?

Comment: this is the link:[stevenrockett.com/family.php?opt=view&album_id=1&photo_id=5](http://stevenrockett.com/family.php?opt=view&album_id=1&photo_id=5)

Comment: Well, I can't find the `background` of your `.navigator` class at all. There is in fact a `background gradient` set by CSS. Try this: `background-image:url('../images/nav.png)` - but I can't really help with your link.

Comment: this is the link:[stevenrockett.com/family.php?opt=view&album_id=1&photo_id=5](http://stevenrockett.com/family.php?opt=view&album_id=1&photo_id=5)
and here is the css: [style.css](http://jsfiddle.net/marsbox2013/jLHMS/)
sorry it took so long to paste the css. . .

Comment: As I already have said: I can't find the `background:url(...)` part in your link. Please considder cleaning up your code, until nothing but the lines involved in your problems remain.

Comment: it's in this part of the css. . .there is i link a created using jsfiddle. . .it's in this part:
#mcts1 .navPrev, #mcts1 .navNext, #mcts1 .navPlay, #mcts1 .navPause 
{
    width:16px; height:22px; position:absolute;  
    background:url('../images/nav.png'); 
    display:inline-block; z-index:5; cursor:pointer;
}

Comment: I see a css3 gradient, not an image.

Comment: `it's in this part of the css` That CSS does not appear in your online style sheet. :-)

Comment: i meant this css : [styles.css](http://jsfiddle.net/marsbox2013/jLHMS/)
sorry, my bad :)

Comment: Are you using any JS libraries/plugins that have an effect on your navigator class?

Comment: yes, it's actually premade and i got it online.
i just integrated it with the website.
here is the .js and .css file [link](http://jsfiddle.net/marsbox2013/jLHMS/)

Comment: the thing is that, everything works-functions and styles(cross browser) in xampp(localhost). . .but when i deployed it online using godaddy as a provider. . .this was the result.

Comment: Are you editing your site currently?  Because it looks like everything is working fine when I look at it.  There is no `background-image: none;` inline and your stylesheet is adding a gradient.

Comment: my bad, i actually posted the wrong code. . .sorry guyz. . . i have updated the question, hope i got it right this time. . .thanks for the time :) really sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your CSS starting on line 311 to this:

```
 .navigator{
background: #efefef url(../images/nav.png); 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%) url(../images/nav.png);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #bbbbbb 100%) url(../images/nav.png); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#bbbbbb 100%) url(../images/nav.png); 
  }
```

Comment: i didnt actually realized that .navigator had a duplicate. . .i had updated the files. . .please have a look if you have time

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be coming somewhere from js or jquery..